# Inserting three minipages in the same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to insert three `minipages`, side by side, in a line, but I'm failing miserably.

Here's what I've been able to do so far:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{
\begin{minipage}{0.4\hsize}

\centering
\scalebox{1.1}{
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{c l l}
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Transactions} \\
    \hline
    id & Initial & Ordered \\
    \hline
    1 & c a     & a c     \\
    2 & c b e a & b c e   \\
    3 & d a c   & a c d   \\
    4 & b a     & a b     \\
    5 & b d c   & b c d   \\
    6 & a b d e & a b d e \\
    6 & e a     & a e     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{minipage}
\hfill \vrule \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\hsize}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt]

    % Tree 1
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {a:2}
    child { node {c:1}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {1} }
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {3} } } } }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {e:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {2} } } } }
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}
\hfill \vrule \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\hsize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt]

    % Tree 2
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {5} } } } }
    child { node {a:2}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {6} }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {4} } } }
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

I'd like to have the `minipages` side by side, separated by vertical lines, and, if possible, I'd like to add a box around the result.

cmhughes, thanks for your reply. Although it works much better than what I had, it still uses less than the available space in the page. My point is, why isn't the `fbox` you've inserted taking the entire `linewidth` of the page.

I'm not sure if it is the `linewidth`, or the `textwidth`, or even the `hsize` I'm willing to refer to; I just would like to have the three minipages, side-by-side, using the "whole" page width available -- naturally, considering the initial margins of the page.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another possibility using a simple `tabular` (no `minipage`s required); the tabular width will be equal to `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-1.33333\fboxrule\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|M{.46\textwidth}|M{.27\textwidth}|M{.27\textwidth}|}
\hline
& & \\
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
\begin{tabular}{c l l}
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Transactions} \\
    \hline
    id & Initial & Ordered \\
    \hline
    1 & c a     & a c     \\
    2 & c b e a & b c e   \\
    3 & d a c   & a c d   \\
    4 & b a     & a b     \\
    5 & b d c   & b c d   \\
    6 & a b d e & a b d e \\
    6 & e a     & a e     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    % Tree 1
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {a:2}
    child { node {c:1}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {1} }
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {3} } } } }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {e:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {2} } } } }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    % Tree 2
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {5} } } } }
    child { node {a:2}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {6} }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {4} } } }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\\ 
& & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for; would you mind just to point out what was that you've done, concerning the `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-1.33333\fboxrule\relax}}` definition/usage. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Rubens since the tabular has three columns and four vertical lines that have some width, each column width has to be reduced by 4/3 of the line width; `\dimexpr` is an e-TeX command allowing to perform calculations with dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gonzalo! So, `dimexpr#1-1.33333\fboxrule` takes, for example, `{.46\textwidth}`, subtracts `1.3 * \fboxrule` from it, and set `p{resulting_size\relax}`? If so, `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{...}}` creates a new type of column that is inserting the contents into a `p{}`, and `\centering` the `p{}` block. Is it right? The `>` and `\arraybackslash` are just part of the syntax, or do they have a special meaning?

Comment: @Rubens: The first part (the one about the width calculation) is almost perfect; `\relax` is only used so TeX stops scanning for further dimensions. The second part (the one about the new column type) is correct. The `>{code}` construct inserts code before the column content is typeset; in this case, `\centering` is inserted before the column content is typeset, so the contents get centered. `\centering` redefines the line changing command ` \\ ` and `\arraybackslash` reverts to the original definition. More details can be found in the documentation of the `array` package.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of your code that does what you want- I've used a simple `fbox` to frame the result- you could get more extravagant using [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed) if you wish.

[image: screenshot]

Here's what I did:

- removed `\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{`, and worked purely with the lengths in the `minipage`s
- changed `hsize` to `linewidth`
- added an `fbox` around the whole thing
- added `%` after each `\end{minipage}` to avoid the extra space being added
- added `\centering` to each `minipage`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{c l l}
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Transactions} \\
    \hline
    id & Initial & Ordered \\
    \hline
    1 & c a     & a c     \\
    2 & c b e a & b c e   \\
    3 & d a c   & a c d   \\
    4 & b a     & a b     \\
    5 & b d c   & b c d   \\
    6 & a b d e & a b d e \\
    6 & e a     & a e     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill \vrule \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt]
    % Tree 1
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {a:2}
    child { node {c:1}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {1} }
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {3} } } } }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {e:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {2} } } } }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill \vrule \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt]
    % Tree 2
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {5} } } } }
    child { node {a:2}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {6} }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {4} } } }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; there's quite some space left by the right side; is there anyway to force the picture to take place over the page line in a whole? I mean, is there a way to increase the width, and center the entries in each field?

Comment: @Rubens oops, forgot the `centering` in the third `minipage`, have corrected :)

Comment: @cmhughes regarding the first new requirement (in the OP's comment) you can enclose the whole thing in another minipage of the appropriate width: `\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}\begin{minipage}{-45\linewidth}...\end{minipage}\end{minipage}}`.

Comment: Would you mind to see my edit? I'm still not satisfied with the width of the resulting picture.

Comment: @Rubens: see my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
 \documentclass{article}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just to show frames of page

% -------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}\hline
 && \\ 
\begin{minipage}{0.46\linewidth}
\centering
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{c l l}
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Transactions} \\
    \hline
    id & Initial & Ordered \\
    \hline
    1 & c a     & a c     \\
    2 & c b e a & b c e   \\
    3 & d a c   & a c d   \\
    4 & b a     & a b     \\
    5 & b d c   & b c d   \\
    6 & a b d e & a b d e \\
    6 & e a     & a e     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
 &%
\begin{minipage}{.27\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt]
    % Tree 1
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {a:2}
    child { node {c:1}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {1} }
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {3} } } } }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {e:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {2} } } } }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
 &
\begin{minipage}{.27\linewidth}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance = 30pt]
    % Tree 2
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, minimum size=5pt,
        scale=0.8]
    \node {\#:3}
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node {c:1}
    child { node {d:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {5} } } } }
    child { node {a:2}[sibling distance=30pt]
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {6} }
    child { node {b:1}
    child { node[rectangle, draw] {4} } } }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{minipage}%
\\%
 && \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's even prettier now, with the inner contents not plastered with the vertical lines; the `showframe` is very handy, didn't know there was such thing. Would you mind to explain what is that with the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` and the subsequent `\renewcommand` of the same `\arraystrech`? Also, what are all those `@` in the `tabular` definition? A last question: how could I add a small padding between the top and bottom lines and the content of each minipage? Thank you all for the support.